# spring storedprocedure in out parameter usage

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate, java-stored-procedures

Hi I am invoking an oracle stored procedure which takes an in out parameter.
I am invoking the the procedure from my class which extends from spring's StoredProcedure class.Based on number of posts I have declared the inout parameter as out parameter in my class and also passed a value to the parameter in my mapping function.
The problem is that it works only as a out parameter but not as in parameter.Can someone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

```
public class MyService extends StoredProcedure {
    public MyService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate,String sqlString) {
        setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);        
        setSql(sqlString);
        setFunction(false);                       
        declareParameter( new SqlOutParameter("inoutparam",OracleTypes.INTEGER));
        declareParameter( new SqlParameter("inparam",Types.VARCHAR));
        compile();
    }

    public Map execute(int arg1,String arg2) {
        Map<String, Object> inParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        inParams.put("inoutparam", arg1);
        inParams.put("inparam", arg2);      
        Map<String,Object> map = execute(inParams);
        return map;          
    }
}


PROCEDURE prc_my_proc (
 inoutparam        IN OUT NUMBER,
 inparam             VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO save_log values ( inoutparam,sysdate);
inoutparam := 100;
END prc_my_proc;
```

Comment: resolved it by using declareParameter( new SqlInOutParameter("inoutparam",OracleTypes.INTEGER));